# Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-layout

I changed my code like below;

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
        setContentView(R.layout.harita);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        boolean kontrol = true; 
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String enlem = "";
        if(bundle.getString("enlem") != null)
        {
            enlem = bundle.getString("enlem");
        }
        else
        {
            kontrol = false;
        }

        String boylam = "";
        if(bundle.getString("boylam") != null)
        {
            boylam = bundle.getString("boylam");
        }
        else
        {
            kontrol = false;
        }

        String baslik = "";
        if(bundle.getString("baslik") != null)
        {
            baslik = bundle.getString("baslik");
        }
        else
        {
            kontrol = false;
        }

        if (kontrol == true) {
            GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.haritaFragment)).getMap();

            LatLng position = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(enlem),Double.parseDouble(boylam));

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 13));

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(baslik).snippet("Baslik").position(position));
        }
    }
```

and my layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/haritaFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

I also add this code to my Manifest.xml;

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

And it's value is like that in strings.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">4030500</integer>
</resources>
```

I changed my codes. And now i get an error like "Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment" on setContentView try catch block.

Comment: please post your Logcat..

Comment: You are missing `<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` add this in your manifest..

Comment: http://s18.postimg.org/fm02tmfvt/logcat.jpg

Comment: Myabe you need to set in your project the link with the google play services library

Comment: Eclipse\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs  ??? I add this library

Comment: If you are using eclipse: right click on your project, click on properties, select "Android", on the bottom there are the "library" option for your project, you need to click "add" and select the google play services library after you imported it in eclipse and you compiled it.

Comment: i did it. from Eclipse\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs folder.

Comment: post your new logcat please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible problems:

- You might need to encapsulate your fragment.
- Your API level should be over 8
- You should add the library from the Project->Properties->Android
- If you're running the Map Demo in the same workspace, I'd recommend to remove it.
- This problem seem not to related to device but try test on device not emulator

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```